# Rails - Uniqueness causing "Stack Too Deep" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, unique

I'm currently working on an API and in my model(called Roast) it belongs to two users. One being the creator, the other the receiver. My current problem, is that I only want ONE instance where these two users can be involved with each other. I found an [article][1] that had a problem just like mine that created the validator but my problem goes down to the stack problem. I'm not sure where this loop is occurring, so I hope you guys can help me with this issue.

```
# roast.rb

class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  validates :roast_creator, uniqueness: { scope: :roast_receiver }

  belongs_to :roast_creator, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_creator
  belongs_to :roast_receiver, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_receiver

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  def last_responder

  end

  def last_reply
    return self.comments.order('comments.created_at DESC').limit(1).load[0] if self.comments.length > 0
  end
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  has_many :created_roasts, :class_name => :Roast, :foreign_key => :roast_creator
  has_many :received_roasts, :class_name => :Roast, :foreign_key => :roast_receiver

  has_many :comments
end

# roasts_controller
class RoastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_roast, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :respond]

  # GET /roasts
  # GET /roasts.json
  def index
    @roasts = Roast.all
  end

  # GET /roasts/1
  # GET /roasts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # POST /roasts
  # POST /roasts.json
  def create
    @roast = Roast.new
    puts "NEW"
    @roast.roast_creator = current_user
    puts "CREATOR SET"
    @roast.roast_receiver = User.find(params[:receiver])
    puts "RECEIVER SET"
    @comment = @roast.comments.new(user: current_user, content: params[:comment])
    puts "INITIAL COMMENT SET"

    if @roast.save && @comment.save
        puts "SAVE CREATED"
        render :show, status: :created, location: @roast
    else
      render json: @roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /roasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /roasts/1.json
  def update
    if @roast.update(roast_params)
      render :show, status: :ok, location: @roast
    else
      render json: @roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /roasts/1
  # DELETE /roasts/1.json
  def destroy
    if(@roast.creator == current_user)
      @roast.destroy
    end
  end

  def respond
    if (current_user.id == @roast.creator.id || current_user.id == @roast.receiver.id)
      @comment = @roast.comments.create(user: current_user, content: params[:comment])

      if(@comment.save)
        render :show, status: :created, location: @roast
      else
        render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: { error: "Current user is not a creator or a receiver of this particular roast." }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_roast
      @roast = Roast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
end
```

The exact error is:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

app/controllers/roasts_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Thanks in advance for any insight you guys can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured the loop with these two associations:

```
 belongs_to :roast_creator, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_creator
 belongs_to :roast_receiver, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_receiver
```

The `foreign_key` option, specifically. This tells Rails to call the method `roast_receiver` to get the foreign key value, which will call the *association* called `roast_receiver`, which has the foreign key value of `roast_receiver` which will call the association... etc, etc, etc.

The `foreign_key` option here should be pointing to the `roast_receiver_id`, not `roast_receiver`:

```
belongs_to :roast_creator, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_creator_id
belongs_to :roast_receiver, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :roast_receiver_id
```

But Rails will do this automatically for you based off the name of the association, so really you could just have these two lines instead:

```
belongs_to :roast_creator, :class_name => :User
belongs_to :roast_receiver, :class_name => :User
```

Comment: Okay, so after adjusting the migration surrounding the attributes of the roast_receiver & roast_creator, your solution worked! Thank you! I had initially tried this solution, but was met with the error I just solved. If anyone encounters an attribute name error, simply add _id to the end of the attributes in your migration file related to the error!

Comment: If this fixes your problem, please remember to upvote and mark this answer as the accepted one.